# typo3 extbase: show section only on certain pages

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

On a page and all of its subpages, I want to include a certain section. In my default template I added this:

```
<div class="container">
    <f:render section="Productsearch"/>
</div>
```

But I want this section to only be included on certain pages. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different layout on these pages. You can probably do this by using a setting (`plugins.tx_yourext.settings.layoutName = Layout2.html`), and then using that in the template:

```
<f:layout name="{settings.layoutName}"/>
```

The layout on the special pages renders the section, the usual layout does not render it.

**EDIT**: You could also just use a condition in the layout. Set `plugins.tx_yourext.settings.showProductSearch = 1` (or 0) on the pages, preferrably using a TypoScript constant. Then use it in a condition:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.showProductSearch}">
    <f:render section="Productsearch"/>
</f:if>
```

Comment: But its a huge convoluted layout, using a different one for one different section feels weird. is there no other way?

Comment: @Chi: Update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Does it matter which extension I use for this?

Comment: The extension name in the TypoScript matters, it has to be the name (not key!) of the extension you are rendering the template for. If your extension key is e.g. `foo_barBar`, the extension name would be `foobarbar`, I strongly believe. Not sure.